# Latex: Formatting the table of code listings

Tags: latex

I'm trying to include a table of code listings in my Latex document. This is the command I am using:

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

The problem I am facing is, that the title of the code is overlaying with the numbering:

[image]

I would like to have it like this (except for "Code" in place of "Tabelle "), but I can't find a solution for it:

[image]

Comment: Please make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem

Comment: I posted an "answer" that can serve as a starting point for an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code kindly provided by [@Dr. Manuel Kuehner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70909654/2777074), you can make this quick hack to prefix the lol with the word "Code":

```
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97474
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34400
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538069
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Quellcode (in German)}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quellcodeverzeichnis (in German)}

\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.5em}{Code #1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\section{Section}
Some text.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
Code
Code
Code
\end{lstlisting}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :) i would like to have a colon after the number of the Code in the Listing (Code 1: Abfrage...) 

Do you know how to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start :).

```
% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97474
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34400
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538069
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Quellcode (in German)}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quellcodeverzeichnis (in German)}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings

\section{Section}
Some text.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
Code
Code
Code
\end{lstlisting}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]